# Undefined reference, using SFML

Tags: c++, pointers, sfml

I have begun learning SFML at the same time as C++ and do not understand the rules of using `&` and `*` in RenderWindow case. Could you help me?

Main class:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include "Square.h"

int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(200, 200), "SFML works!");
    Square sq(5,5);

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

        window.clear();
        sq.draw(&window);
        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Square header:

```
#ifndef SQUARE_H
#define SQUARE_H
class Square
{
    private:
    sf::RenderWindow* window;
    sf::RectangleShape rectangle;
    int y;
    int x;
    public:
        Square(int coordX, int coordY);
        Square();
        void draw(const sf::RenderWindow* target);
};

#endif
```

Square class:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
class Square{
    sf::RectangleShape rectangle;

    int y;
    int x;
    public:
        Square(int coordX, int coordY)
        : rectangle(), y(coordY),x(coordX)
        {
            rectangle.setSize(sf::Vector2f(10,100));
            rectangle.setOrigin(5,50);
        }
        Square()
        : rectangle(), y(5),x(5)
        {
            rectangle.setSize(sf::Vector2f(10,100));
            rectangle.setOrigin(5,50);
        }
        void draw(sf::RenderWindow* target)
        {
            target->draw(rectangle);
        }
```

I can't draw a square on RenderWindow:

```
main.cpp:(.text+0x17d): undefined reference to `Square::Square(int, int)'
main.cpp:(.text+0x211): undefined reference to `Square::draw(sf::RenderWindow const*)'
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: Did you include square.h in square.cpp?

Comment: yep, now error is:

square.cpp:4:7re-initializing «class Square»
square.h:3:7:previous initializing «class Square»

i put the ';' before #endif in header and removed in .cpp

Comment: That is because you are re-declaring the class in square.cpp. You just need to provide the function implementations and not redefine everything.

Comment: yeaah! i've done it! Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C++, you have function *declaration* and function *definition*:

```
// declaration, typically in X.h
#pragma once // don't include this twice, my dear compiler
class X {
public:
   void foo();
};
```

Implementation:

```
// X.cpp
#include "X.h"
void X::foo() { ...code .... }

// here you wrote
// class X { void foo(){} };
// which is a _declaration_ of class X
// with an _inline definition_ of foo.
```

Usage:

```
// main.cpp
#include "X.h"
```

Applying this pattern to your code should ensure that

- every symbol is defined
- no symbol is defined more than once

Answer (score 0):

Remove square.cpp and change your square.h file to the following. Make sure you take back-up before changing your files.

```
#ifndef SQUARE_H
#define SQUARE_H
class Square
{
    private:
    sf::RenderWindow* window;
    sf::RectangleShape rectangle;
    int y;
    int x;
    public:
        Square(int coordX, int coordY)
        : rectangle(), y(coordY),x(coordX)
        {
            rectangle.setSize(sf::Vector2f(10,100));
            rectangle.setOrigin(5,50);
        }
        Square()
        : rectangle(), y(5),x(5)
        {
            rectangle.setSize(sf::Vector2f(10,100));
            rectangle.setOrigin(5,50);
        }
        void draw(sf::RenderWindow* target)
        {
            target->draw(rectangle);
        }
};

#endif
```